# Align <th> to the center when printing

Tags: html, css, ajax, datatable

I want to align the table header and the body to the center when printing the table.
I use datatable.

So this is how it looks :

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fnyi.png)

I tried to align the th tags on HTML table but when I print it out it goes to the left :|

Here's What I did :

I added class to the table :

```
"columnDefs":[
        {
            "targets":[0,1,2,3],
            "orderable":false,
    className: "dt-head-center"

        },
```

And then styling the class :

```
.dt-head-center {
text-align: center;
}
```

And its not working :\

HELP

Comment: create a snippet with what you have

Comment: @DCR check [Jsbin](https://jsbin.com/huxucalenu/edit?html,css,js,console,output) 
in the actual table the th is centered but when printing it goes to the left

Answer (score 0):

Solved By Using customize.

```
customize: function (win) {
                $(win.document.body).find('table').addClass('display').css('font-size', '9px');
                $(win.document.body).find('tr:nth-child(odd) td').each(function(index){
                    $(this).css('background-color','#D0D0D0');
                });
                $(win.document.body).find('th,td').css('text-align','center');
            }
```